# How to use codebehind to create email hyperlink in asp.net visual basic?

Tags: html, asp.net, email, hyperlink

I've created a hyperlink on a web page, and I'm trying to have it open an email client with a variable email address, so I want to set the email address in the code behind for a hyperlink control. However, when I click the link nothing happens. I'm able to do this for an html link, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Here is my code:

```
Email.NavigateUrl = Me.ResolveUrl(String.Concat("mailto:", Results.sstrEmail))
```

Where Email is the asp:hyperlink control, and results.email is a string containing an email address.

Comment: On your page, what is the href of `Email`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. I didn't set href. I'm using the navigateurl property of the asp.net html control which should take its place. It worked fine on a regular web link, but not for the email.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're doing. I'm asking you to go to the page, and tell me what the link is pointing to on the running/compiled/built site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using the Me.Resolveurl method? The final href of the link should just be href="mailto:mail@domain.com" and should not include the website url.

```
Email.NavigateUrl = String.Concat("mailto:", Results.sstrEmail)
```

Comment: Yes, I actually had it without it initially and had the same result. Thanks though.